# UnicodeEncodeError in django python3

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-unicode

I want to handle the file uploaded by the guest, here is the views code:

```
def charset(request):                                   
    logging.info('charset')                             
    name = request.GET['name']                          
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name) 
    logging.info(file_path)                             
    logging.info(type(file_path))                       
    file1 = open(file_path.decode('utf8'), 'wb')        
    file1.write(b'test')                                
    file1.close()                                       
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

But an error occurred. The trace back is following:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /upload/charset/
    'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 27-28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can repeat the error by visiting: [My Wrong Website](http://www.ramwin.com/upload/charset/?name=%E5%BF%83%E5%81%9A)

I'm using environment as these:

```
python 3.4.3  
django 1.9.3   
apache2 2.4.7
```

But when I run server using `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`. It works.
How can I fix this? Thank you for your attention. You can view the project code on the website [github_of_my_django_tutorial](https://github.com/ramwin/django_tutorial).

Comment: The traceback on that link doesn't match the code you've posted above; there's no `decode` call.

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the code to [this](https://github.com/ramwin/django_tutorial/blob/master/upload/views.py). I should `use encode("utf8")` to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the filename to UTF-8 first:

```
name = name.encode("utf8")
```